# How to define a new instruction in gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to define a new instruction in gem5.

How can we do that?. Or alter the operation of some instructions.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Look at existing instructions. Grep the source code. GDB step debug. Copy one of them and modify it to do what you want.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmk35/gem5-instruction.html) for a complete instruction or [this](http://gedare-csphd.blogspot.com/2013/02/add-pseudo-instruction-to-gem5.html) for pseudo-instruction